# Splitting a String using Regex with Negative Number

Tags: java

how can I possible split this string using **"-"** but also store the negative sign for **"-5"**. I'm using

```
string = "5*5--5";

String[] sub = string.split("-");
```

**Output :**

```
[5*5, , 5]
```

**Output that I want:**

```
[5*5, -5]
```

Comment: First step is to decide exactly what criteria your program should use to decide whether `-` means "subtract two things" or "negative number".  Once you've decided that, you should be able to write an appropriate regular expression to split on.  You'll want to learn about "lookahead" and "lookbehind" regular expressions, in order to work out how to do this.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thanks man. lookahead and lookbehind saves me.